# What is difference between MemoryCacheSize and BitmapPoolSize in Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm curious about `MemorySizeCalculator` of `Glide`. I can get default memory cache size from `getMemoryCacheSize()` and bitmap pool size from `getBitmapPoolSize()`.

**MemorySizeCalculator**:

```
/**
 * Returns the recommended memory cache size for the device it is run on in bytes.
 */
public int getMemoryCacheSize() {
    return memoryCacheSize;
}

/**
 * Returns the recommended bitmap pool size for the device it is run on in bytes.
 */
public int getBitmapPoolSize() {
    return bitmapPoolSize;
}
```

I understood memory cache concept as well but not sure bitmap pool size, so I found some information from this link : https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/performance-improvement-and-bitmap-pooling-in-android-f97b380cf965

> Bitmap pooling is a simple technique (though fairly complex to
>   implement), that aims to reuse bitmaps instead of creating new ones
>   every time. To put it simply, when you need a bitmap, you check a
>   bitmap stack to see if there are any bitmaps available. If there are
>   not bitmaps available you create a new bitmap otherwise you pop a
>   bitmap from the stack and reuse it. Then when you are done with the
>   bitmap, you can put it on a stack.

I think that the bitmap which is pushed to a stack is also cached on memory. Is there anyone who can help me understand this concept?

Answer (score 1):

1. bitmap pool cached **dirty** bitmap, that used to save time to create
   bitmap. because we can't promise all of bitmap cached in
   memoryCache.
2. memoryCache cached bitmap which you have used before.

Answer (score 0):

Image heavy applications have to decode many images, so there will be continuous allocation and deallocation of memory in application. This results in frequent calling of the Garbage Collector (GC). And if you call the GC too many times, your application UI freezes. Glide use the Bitmap Pool Concept to load images efficiently. By using the Bitmap pool to avoid continuous allocation and deallocation of memory in your application, you reduce GC overhead, which results in a smooth-running application.

The basic principe is simple. When processing bitmap you have to verify if bitmap 2 is the same as bitmap 1. For this, you have to compare them. If it is the case you can reuse bitmap 1 as an inbitmap to reuse the same memory space to process gitmap 2 then skiping GC.

Memory cache is a memory space allocated to each application. One application cannot access the cache memory of other application.. It's size is limited.